# Space Filling Curse passing through arbitrary grid cell's neighbors continuously

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

Given a $M×M×M$ 3D cube grid $\mathbf C$, how can I map the 3D grid-coordinates to 1D coordinates such that every cell's nearest neighbors (mostly $3\times 3\times 3$ area around the grid cell) can be represented by a continuous range of corresponding 1D values?

One of the possible 3D-to-1D mappings could be [Z-indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), but I don't know how to access the neighbors in the way I described above.

*(This is crosspost from https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/nearest-neighbors-in-radius-via-z-order-order-curve)*

Comment: I wanted to edit "curse" to "curve" in the title, but decided it's better as is ...

Comment: @EthanBolker :D thanks for spotting that! Now I also don't know if I want to edit the title.

Comment: Space Killing Curse would have been an even more interesting typo.